# Session delete mysqli

Tags: php, session, mysqli, sql-delete

I have 2 web pages which
amend a news blog, and if I want to delete a blog it opens up delete.php.

I retrieve the blogs using

```
$query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM `news` order by date DESC'); 

$query->execute(); 
$query->store_result(); 
$query->bind_result($id,$title); 

while ($query->fetch()) {


$_SESSION['id'] = $id ;
$_SESSION['title'] = $title ;
<a href="deletenews.php">
}
```

I  make 2 sessions for the `$id` and `$title`.
I have a delete button, that goes to delete.php,

```
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
$title = $_SESSION['title'];



 $query = $db->prepare('DELETE  FROM `news` WHERE id = ? and title = ?'); 
 $query->bind_param('ss', $id, $title);
 $query->execute(); 

unset($_SESSION['id']);
unset($_SESSION['title']);
header("location: news.php");
```

I call the `$id` and `$title` session to test, on amend page, which is working fine, but when it goes over to delete.php, it changes.
It is deleting from the database, but instead of e.g. id 1 it will delete id 2, it will delete the next one up the list in the database.
I find it very strange.

If anyone could help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have 2 records the first one id = 1, second id = 2

```
while ($query->fetch()) {


   $_SESSION['id'] = $id ;
   //First loop $_SESSION['id'] = 1
   //second loop $_SESSION['id'] = 2
   $_SESSION['title'] = $title ;
   <a href="deletenews.php">
}
// at the end $_SESSION['id'] = 2
```

What you want to do is

```
while ($query->fetch()) {

   <a href="deletenews.php?id=$id&title=$title">
   //it will link the link ;) with the id of the news
}
```

The changes in delete.php will be :

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$title = $_GET['title'];
```

have fun